# probability of a single value belonging to a population

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, descriptive-statistics

what is the appropriate approach to estimate the probability of a single sample belonging to a population?

Specifically, I am calculating a particular value from the comparison of two time series. Then, I perform many rounds of shifting the time series against each other by random amounts of time and re-calculating those values. 
Finally, I would like to determine if the obtained single value from the original time series is different from the family of values obtained from the shifted time series.

In other words, I would like to test if shifting the time series does or does not have an effect on my value. Obviously, I only have ONE un-shifted value which I want to compare to MANY values from time series shifted by various amounts.

I looked up one sample t-tests but the logic is typically reversed from what I read online: typically, the mean of a 'single sample' is compared to a 'known' value.

would this still be the right test?